# Best alternative for asp:UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have a very large project created with ASP.Net 3.5. In that project in many places asp:UpdatePanel is used. Sometimes nested ones too.

There is a page which search for a customer and displays his basic information and address information in two separate grids. These grids are in two separate UpdatePanels. Users complained that the page get hangs after couple of search requests (after around 10-15 search requests)

I have introduced asp:UpdateProgress, but that also didn't help. Any alternative way I can resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery with ASP.NET Ajax PageMethods:

http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

and [performance will also be boosted](http://encosia.com/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/) comparing to update panel..

Comment: If I add this, will it affect on other pages too ? which uses Update Panels and other Ajax controls.